# AWS SDK getOjbect does not return a file

Tags: javascript, amazon-web-services, aws-sdk

I'm using AWS SDK in order to retrieve data from a S3 bucket, but the response I get does not contain any data.

**Here's my code:**

```
const init = (S3_REGION) => {
    AWS.config.update({
            'region': S3_REGION
        }
    );
    return new AWS.S3();
};

const getFileFromAWS = async (S3_REGION, S3_BUCKET) => {
    const s3 = init(S3_REGION);
    const params = {
      Bucket: S3_BUCKET,
      Key: "filename.txt"
    };
    try{
        const awsResponse = await s3.getObject(params);
        logger.info(awsResponse);
    }catch(error){
      logger.error('Failed to get file');
    }
};
```

The response returns 'data: null', if I send a curl request I get the file.
Note, that I only send the 'region' because I'm running in an env where all rest of variables are already set, I just need to pass the region.

**Response I get from getObject**

```
    "Body ": {
    "type ": "Buffer ",
    "data ": [
        115,
        97,
        108,
        116,
        10
    ]
}
```

How to I convert it to string?
Please advise.

Comment: The getObject() method returns an AWS.Request object, which is not a promise. You should use getObject(params).promise().

Comment: @jarmod, thanks! you are right. Now in the data I get an object back, 
how do I convert it to the string the file contains?
Posted the response in original question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The getObject() method returns an [AWS.Request](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/Request.html) object, which is not a promise. You should use:

```
const rsp = await s3.getObject(params).promise()
```

To retrieve the contents of the downloaded file as a text string, you can use a variant of:

```
const txt = rsp.Body.toString('utf-8')
```

For more detail on using promises with the JavaScript SDK, see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/using-promises.html).

Comment: Tried the 'toString' but I either get "115,97,108,116,10" or "[object Object]", tried with base64, same result.

Comment: Is it actually a text file? I've updated the answer above and this code works for me.